# Extract text starting from negated set up til (but not including) first occurance of @

Tags: regex, autohotkey, regex-group, regex-negation

good day community.

Say I have the following line:

```
    [ ] This is a sentence about apples. @fruit @tag
```

I wish to create a regex that can generically extract the portion:
"This is a sentence about apples." only.

That is, ignore the       `[ ]` before the sentence, and ignore `@fruit @tag` after.

What I have so far is: `([^\s*\[\s\]\s])(.*@)`

Which is creating the following match:
`This is a sentence about apples. @fruit @`

How would I match up to, but not including the first occurrence of `@` symbol, while still negating       `[ ]` pattern with `([^\s*\[\s\]\s])` group?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for the critical piece to help:

```
RegExMatch(str, "O)\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])", output)
```

Final code:

```
; Zim Inbox txt file
FileEncoding, UTF-8
File := "C:\Users\dragoon\Desktop\anki_cards.txt"

; sleep is necessary

;;Highlight line and copy
#IfWinActive ahk_exe zim.exe
{
clipboard=
sleep, 500
Send ^+c
ClipWait
Send ^{Down}
clipboardQuestion := clipboard
FoundQuestion := RegExMatch(clipboardQuestion,"O)\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])",outputquestion)

clipboard=
sleep, 500
Send ^+c
ClipWait
clipboardAnswer := clipboard
FoundAnswer := RegExMatch(clipboardAnswer,"O)\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])",outputanswer)

quotedQuestionAnswer := outputquestion[1] """" outputanswer[1] """"

Fileappend, %quotedQuestionAnswer%, %File%
}
```

What it does:
In Zim Wiki notebook, on Windows, press Win+V hotkey over Question? in the following structure:

```
[ ] Question Header
    [ ] Question?
        [ ] Answer about dogs @cat @dog
```

This will result in the text being formatted as such in an external file:

```
Question?"Answer about dogs"
```

This is an acceptable format for Anki card importing, and can be used to quickly make cards from a review structure. Thanks again for all the help on my first SO question.

Comment: Try `\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])`, see https://regex101.com/r/BeHR8Q/1. Group 1 value will contain one  or more chars other than `@` after `[ ]` substring.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Actually, Wiktor's answer is the closest to what I'm seeking so far. The output is now "[ ] This is a sentence about apples."
Would it be possible for the match to exclude the brackets in result?
Seeking "This is a sentence about apples."

Comment: They are already excluded, I used a group and the text you need is in Group 1. What is the programming language?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This is in an autohotkey script, but I'm flexible as it's going to modify plain text. I'll apply your approach now in the script and confirm back if it's working.

Comment: Try `RegExMatch(str, "O)\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])", output)` and then use `output[1]`. Well, you may also use `\[\s*]\s*\K[^@]*[^@\s]` since AHK uses PCRE.

Comment: That last comment helped so much, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[\s*]\s*\K[^@]*[^@\s]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BeHR8Q/2). *Details*:

- `\[\s*]\s*` - `[`, zero or more whitespaces, `]`, zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - "forget" what has just been matched
- `[^@]*` - zero or more chars other than `@`
- `[^@\s]` - a char other than `@` and whitespace.

Note that in AutoHotKey, you can also *capture* the part of a match if use *Object mode*:

```
RegExMatch(str, "O)\[\s*]\s*([^@]*[^@\s])", output)
```

The string you want to use is captured with Group 1 pattern (defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses) and you can access it via `output[1]`. See [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm):

> Object mode. [v1.1.05+]: This causes RegExMatch() to yield all information of the match and its subpatterns to a [match object](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#MatchObject) in OutputVar. For details, see [OutputVar](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#ObjectMode).